# Oracle - Can this query be simplified or reorganized?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, set, alias

I am making a query generator for that will translate business rules into SQL queries to be run against an Oracle database. The rules are essentially of the form "All items matching these criteria should be related to an item matching these criteria". After much thought and deliberation, I have determined that the best way to do this is to use SQL to join two sets:

1. The set of all items matching the FROM criteria (A)
2. The set of all items matching the FROM criteria that ARE related to items matching the TO criteria (B)

It is necessary that B is a subset of A. I will determine if a rule is met by subtracting B from A and expecting an empty set. If the set is not empty, the rule is not met.

There are many Google image results for "SQL join" that show how to represent various set relationships using the different types of join statements, such as [this image](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg). The one I want to go with (for A - B) would be the middle one on the left:

```
   select A.id
     from items A
left join items B
       on A.id = B.id
    where B.id = null
```

Obviously my query is much more complicated than this. The way I have been doing this is by making B a subquery. I also have to include the relationship table and then add the criteria. A resulting template:

```
   select A.id
     from items A
left join (
          select A.id
            from items A
            join relationships rel
              on rel.from_item = A.id
            join items to
              on rel.to_item = to.id
           where [from criteria]
             and [to criteria]
          ) B
       on A.id = B.id
     join relationships rel
       on rel.from_item = A.id
    where B.id = null
      and [from criteria]
```

Is there a better way, syntactically, for me to perform the query I am trying to perform?

I am picturing something where I can construct query A as something like a temp table, then construct query B from query A, and then have one final query left join them together and return a result. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want subquery factoring-- the `WITH` clause

```
WITH first_set AS (
  select A.id
    from items A
         join relationships rel
           on rel.from_item = A.id
         join items to
           on rel.to_item = to.id
   where [from criteria]
),
second_set AS (
  select a.id
    from first_set a
   where [to criteria]
)
SELECT a.id
  FROM first_set a
       left join second_set b
         on a.id = b.id
 WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

Personally, I would find it clearer when building the final query to use a `NOT EXISTS` or a `MINUS` rather than doing a `LEFT JOIN` and checking for `NULL`.  The `LEFT JOIN` approach works and it may well be just as efficient as the other alternatives.  It always strikes me as a bit counterintuitive.